# Conditional statement refactor

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I trying to find information about refactoring of conditional statements. I would like to short up this comparison, do you have any ideas is it generally possible?

```
if 'text1' in somelist or 'text2' in somelist:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your expression is readable, but an alternative would be the following:

```
if any(x in somelist for x in ['text1', 'text2']):
   do_something()
```